# Simple UML OOP style software planning tool?

Tags: java, oop, uml

I heard of UML from this java book I'm reading through right now and got interested in it, I can't seem to make sense of what people are saying in regards to these products. I'm basically a pretty new programmer, I have self-taught myself the basics of Python and made a few GUI apps.

I have also worked my way through the C-standard and messed around with GTK+ 3.0 a bit and I am working on learning Java right now, I don't have a lot of experience with OOP so I was wanting a tool that could help me grasp this by allowing me to plan out my software through a tree like structure. If someone could refer a basic tool that isn't hard to learn for me to start off on that would be really great.

Comment: [Star UML](http://staruml.io/) might help you as well. This is free to download and use.

Comment: You may want to try [softwarerecs.se] if you still need help.

Comment: Thanks @MandarPandit This one looks really nice too. I'm going to try this one out until I can afford Visio

Comment: I agree with 'Second Rikudo', Refer to [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Yeah, thanks and sorry I didn't realize there was a section dedicated to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has `Visio 2012` which has a template specifically for UML diagrams allowing you to plan out your program's structure.

I love this software, makes your diagrams look very good and professional. Also, it's super easy to learn. You could easily learn to make UML diagrams within a day with this.

You can also create use-cases, and other goodies that will allow you to map out your plan of attack on your project!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, Nice looking software too